# Python script not running when called from run-parts through a USBmount

Tags: bash, scripts, python

I'm running Ubuntu Server and have a python script I am trying to have automatically run when a USB drive is plugged in, however the script is not run when usbmount executes its run-parts command. If I run run-parts myself the script runs fine. I have put in some logging into my bash script and it shows that the script is actually being called when a usb drive is plugged in, it just doesn't execute my python script.

I've been pulling my hair out over this all day, I'm thinking maybe there's a permissions problem that is not allowing usbmount to execute the python script, but if there is I can't figure it out.

Clarification: I have a shell script in /etc/usbmount/mount.d that logs when it is called and then calls my python script.

Comment: If possible, post the bash script that you've referenced, as well as Python script.  If the issue with the syntax, we can't know without seeing the code.  I've never heard about `run-parts`. Is there a reason you're not using `udev` subsystem for running the script ?

Comment: The usbmount documentation uses /etc/usbmount/mount.d as a location for hook scripts and provides environmental variables to scripts it executes in that folder. https://github.com/rbrito/usbmount#hook-scripts

My shell script is really really simple:

#!/bin/sh

logger "Ingest Script run, Mountpoint: $UM_MOUNTPOINT"

python3 /home/user/scripts/ingestion/ingest.py "$UM_MOUNTPOINT" &

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about usbmount but here's the reason for a similar case: `/etc/dhcp/dhclient-exit-hooks.d/`
In that particular case, the hooks are executed by `/bin/dhclient-script` as *source* (ie with `.`). `run-parts` is only invoked to get the list of scripts in that folder. `run-parts --list /etc/dhcp/dhclient-exit-hooks.d/`.

Long story short, the scripts have to be *shell* scripts. See below.
However, nothing keeps you from explicitly invoking the python interpreter from that shell script (see further below).

```bsh
# run given script
run_hook() {
    local script="$1"
    local exit_status=0

    if [ -f $script ]; then
        . $script                  # <=== must be shell script
        exit_status=$?
    fi

    if [ -n "$exit_status" ] && [ "$exit_status" -ne 0 ]; then
        logger -p daemon.err "$script returned non-zero exit status $exit_status"
    fi

    return $exit_status
}

# run scripts in given directory
run_hookdir() {
    local dir="$1"
    local exit_status=0

    if [ -d "$dir" ]; then
        for script in $(run-parts --list $dir); do
            run_hook $script
            exit_status=$((exit_status|$?))
        done
    fi

    return $exit_status
}
```

Example of invoking the python script

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
#
# Invoke a python script to update the DNS zone with the WLAN IP address
# The python script is in the same folder but not picked up by run-parts because its name contains a "."
#
PYTHON3_INTERPRETER=$(which python3)
THIS_FOLDER=/etc/dhcp/dhclient-exit-hooks.d
THE_SCRIPT=update_zone.py

${PYTHON3_INTERPRETER} ${THIS_FOLDER}/${THE_SCRIPT}
```